How to force Spring HATEOAS resources to render an empty embedded array in RepresentationModelProcessor?
I have the following processor that aims to handle empty collections of CoachModel and return a JSON response with _embedded when the collection is empty:
@Component
public class CoachPagedModelProcessor implements RepresentationModelProcessor<PagedModel<CoachModel>> {

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public PagedModel<CoachModel> process(@NonNull PagedModel<CoachModel> model) {
        if (model.getContent().isEmpty()) {
            EmbeddedWrappers wrappers = new EmbeddedWrappers(false);
            EmbeddedWrapper wrapper = wrappers.emptyCollectionOf(CoachModel.class);
            List<EmbeddedWrapper> embedded = Collections.singletonList(wrapper);
            model = PagedModel.of(embedded, model.getMetadata(), model.getLinks());
        }

        return model;
    }
}

The goal is to have the processor return a JSON structure with an empty _embedded collection when the list is empty.
The issue is related to generic typing. The processor is designed to handle PagedModel, but when the collection is empty, I need to return PagedModel for the proper representation of an empty collection.
I tried modifying the processor to use a wildcard like this:
public PagedModel<?> process(@NonNull PagedModel<?> model)
However, this leads to another issue: I cannot apply the processor since it's not possible to provide a wildcard (<?>) in the fallback type when calling withFallbackType().
How can I handle the empty collection scenario with RepresentationModelProcessor while keeping a strict PagedModel type for non-empty collections, and ensuring proper JSON output with _embedded for empty collections?
doc : https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#server.processors.empty-collections
CoachModel extends RepresentationModel
